# IOS-Book-Article.cls: addresses in one single line

Tags: article, affiliation

Is it possible to set \address[C], \address[D], and \address[E] in one line, I mean all of 3 addresses on one single line, rather than having each of them on one single line? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{IOS-Book-Article}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}              % The preamble begins here.

\title{Some definitions}
\author[A,B,C]{\fnms{John} \snm{Marc}}%
,
\author[B,D]{\fnms{Peter} \snm{Wolf}}
,
\author[B,E]{\fnms{Dean} \snm{Boy}}

\address[A]{University of \LaTeX, Higher Institute lab}
\address[B]{Some University}

\address[C]{\tt{johnmarc@gmail.com}}
\address[D]{\tt{peterwolf@gmail.com}}
\address[E]{\tt{deanboy@gmail.com}}
\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you're using the class for a submission, leave the decision to the class; otherwise, don't use it.

Comment: I understand that. But I wish I could know how to technically do such thing. I have tried it myself and could not. One day that can do useful elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution, the use of \mbox command as follow:

```
\documentclass{IOS-Book-Article}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}              % The preamble begins here.

\title{Some definitions}
\author[A,B,C]{\fnms{John} \snm{Marc}}%
,
\author[B,D]{\fnms{Peter} \snm{Wolf}}
,
\author[B,E]{\fnms{Dean} \snm{Boy}}

\address[A]{University of \LaTeX, Higher Institute lab}
\address[B]{Some University}

\mbox{    
\address[C]{\tt{johnmarc@gmail.com}}
\address[D]{\tt{peterwolf@gmail.com}}
\address[E]{\tt{deanboy@gmail.com}}}
\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```